# Histogram of two discrete series one by one in R

Tags: r, plot, format, histogram, plotrix

I have two vectors with different lengths in R, which contains integer number only (1,2,3,4,5). I want to plot histogram of them (in percentage, not in count) one by one.

I tried to use `multhist` in the package `plotrix`, but there are two problems:

1. It plots with `y-axis` as count, not percentage.
2. It plots with `x-axis` as float number, such as 1.1, 1.5, etc. while obviously I only need to plot with `x-axis` at 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

How could I do that in R?

Thank you very much,

**Update**:

the code with `multhist`:

``

```
x1 <- round(runif(1000, 1.0, 5.0), digits=0)    
x2 <- round(runif(100, 1.0, 5.0), digits=0)    
require (plotrix)    
multhist (x1,x2)
```

``

Comment: It's ``multhist``. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
multhist(list(x1,x2),breaks=seq(0.5,5.5,by=1),probability=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Thanks a lot,